# Matplotlib and TKinter - Is there a way to have a graph update dynamically with button presses?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am attempting to follow a tutorial that uses TKinter and Matplotlib to produce graphs on a frame of a tkinter app.
A problem that I have run in to is that the graph is not reloaded when I press the button. The command starts as soon as the program starts and does not run again upon being pressed.

Below is the code that I run:

```
class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Sea of BTC client")
        
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

        
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph Page",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
        button3.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()


class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()
        f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        a = f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


        

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```

The button for viewing the plot screen does not dynamically create the plot, pressing the button fails to update anything.

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the logic for plotting the matplotlib figure into a separate method and call it whenever the button is pressed for the graph frame/page.  This means you will need a separate method for that specific button as well because it will need to call the graphing logic method when fired.  The example below does both, now whenever you click the button you will see a new random graph every time it shows the graph frame.

for example:

```
import random
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, ttk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Sea of BTC client")


        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph Page",
                            command=self.show_graph)
        button3.pack()

    def show_graph(self):
        self.controller.show_frame(PageThree)
        graph = self.controller.frames[PageThree]
        graph.plot()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page Two!!!")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()


class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph Page!")
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()
        self.f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, self)

    def plot(self):
        self.f.clear()
        a = self.f.add_subplot(111)
        a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[random.randint(1,34) for _ in range(10)])
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

app = SeaofBTCapp()
app.mainloop()
```